# Can anyone identify this microorganism?

Tags: species-identification, microbiology

I was examining some rainwater from my backyard in Richmond, VA, and found this microorganism. I took some pictures of it at 400x and 1000x (see below). The microorganism is attached to some moss and appears to be using it as an anchor while hunting/feeding. While feeding, it stretches out and searches for food, and once it catches something, it snaps back into itself. I also got some pictures of the microorganism while resting.

[image: Image 1 - feeding]
[image: Image 2 - feeding]
[image: Image 3 - resting]

I'm not sure what this is and would appreciate any input. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They seem to be rotifers, the fuzzy (supposedly rotating) mouthparts are part of what convinces me. The behavior you mentioned of latching on the moss with their 'tails' is also a characteristic behavior of rotifers. They are also able to retract their bodies just as you mentioned.

Here are some images of rotifers that might support the argument.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am least certain about the last image but I am making the assumption for now that it is either some variety of circular/retracted rotifer or a completely different kind of microorganism.

Stay curios!

Comment: by a moment I thought you were Joe Hanson. LOL